# Find the normal form of a plane $\pi$ which contains three points

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have three points $(2, 3, 0), (1, 5, 2)$ and $(−1, 4, 3)$. These three points describes a plane $\pi$. It is easy to obtain the normal form using the direction vectors but I'm looking for a *full* solution using a system of linear equation/matrix.

The solution will have the form $ax+by+cz+d=0$. Using the three points we get the following $\begin{cases} 2a+3b+d=0\\ a+5b+2c+d=0 \\ -a+4b+3c+d=0\end{cases}\iff \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\1 & 5 & 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 4 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}=0$ So we get 4 unknowns and 3 equation. If the plane passes through origin then $d=0$ and we get a system of 3 unknowns and 3 equations instead which is easy to solve.  But is it possible to solve this system of linear equation that we have without any more information?

Comment: These 4 unknown and 3 (independent) equations give you a line of solutions $(a,b,c,d)=k(a_0,b_0,c_0,c_0)$. This is not surprising, as any of them (excluding $(0,0,0,0)$) gives the same plane.

Comment: Write down the vector form of the plane in terms of two parameters (s and t say). You now have x, y and z on the plane in terms of s and t. Find s and t in terms of x and y then substitute those into your expression for z.

Comment: @Paul this is not the method chosen by the OP. He had nearly finished but was just embarassed to have 1 more unknown than equations.

Comment: I still don't know if it is possible to get the normal form through this method. I have looked around and it is talked about but I have never seen it fully solved with this method...

Comment: What prevents you to "fully" solve that homogeneous system of  4 unknown and 3 equations? You will get an infinite set of solutions $(a,b,c,d),$ proportional to eachother hence giving the "same" *cartesian equation*. Isn't that what you call "normal form"?

Comment: I just don't know I just have many stupid questions that I don't need to ask if I can see it solved and explained somewhat because then I'll understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your favorite method you get the solutions of the system:$$(4d,-3d,5d,d),\quad d\in\mathbb R.$$
Hence "the" equation of your plane (up to proportionality) is:$$4x-3y+5z+1=0.$$
(You may check that your three points satisfy this equation.)

Comment: See now I understand, and what you commented earlier makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: The problem I had was the free variable that is obtained by solving  the system of linear equation with 3 independent equations and 4 unknowns. I failed to see the connection that $4x-3y+5z+1=0\iff t(4x-3y+5z+1)=0$, where $t\in\mathbb{R}$ is the free variable.